Oat grain segmentation when grains are touching
The needed result is to segment each of the grains separately using image processing methods.
Used images:
First image
Second image
I have tried using Canny's edge detection, Connected Components analysis method but found out that a lot of use Watershed for problems like this, where objects are touching. However, my end results is not perfect and as you can see in the images below, some of the grains are considered as one object. Is there something more that I could do, to achieve better result?
First image example results
Second image example results
The code:
def threshold_lab(image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)
    a_channel = lab[:, :, 1]
    mask = cv2.threshold(a_channel, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    return mask


def watershed_algorithm(image: np.ndarray):
    thresh = threshold_lab(image)

    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    definite_bg = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)

    # Finding sure foreground area
    dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(thresh, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
    ret, definite_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.25 * dist_transform.max(), 255, 0)

    # Finding unknown region
    definite_fg = np.uint8(definite_fg)
    pending_areas = cv2.subtract(definite_bg, definite_fg)

    # Marker labelling
    ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(definite_fg)
    markers = markers + 1
    markers[pending_areas == 255] = 0
    markers = cv2.watershed(image, markers)

    # Dilate the markers to make the lines thicker
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    markers_dilated = cv2.dilate((markers == -1).astype(np.uint8), kernel, iterations=1)

    # Overlay the dilated markers on the original image
    original_copy = image.copy()
    original_copy[markers_dilated == 1] = [255, 0, 0]

    titles = ['Original', 'LAB thresholded',  'Labeling image', 'Segmentation image']
    images = [image, thresh, markers, original_copy]

    for i in range(len(images)):
        plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1), plt.imshow(images[i], 'gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
        plt.title(titles[i])
        plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()


Fix the indentation.
